# json image url error MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, image-gallery

I am developing image android app Is there a way to save the images from server to sd card using following code. its work but get 1st image only get when second image loop executed protocol not found errors getting. didn't get all images how to get all images
[this is my 1st URL](http://192.168.1.3:8080/emenu/images/restaurant1.png),[2nd URL](http://192.168.1.3:8080/emenu/images/restaurant2.png)

```
     for (int i = 0; i < merchant_details.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = merchant_details.getJSONObject(i);
                    URL url = new URL (l.getString("merchant_image"));
                    InputStream input = url.openStream();
                     try {
                            //The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly, or
                            //more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath,"myimage.png"));
                             try {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2024];
                                    int bytesRead = 0;
                                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                    }
                                } finally {
                                    output.close();
                                }
                            } finally {
                                input.close();
                            }
en04-16 13:47:01.128    2664-2665/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed    741K, 7% free 12694K/13575K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 19ms
04-16 13:47:01.212    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
 04-16 13:47:01.212    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at emenu.lists.order.Home$GetMerchant_details.doInBackground(Home.java:316)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at emenu.lists.order.Home$GetMerchant_details.doInBackground(Home.java:275)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-16 13:47:01.216    2664-2680/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-16 13:47:04.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:09.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:14.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
  04-16 13:47:19.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:24.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:29.868      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:34.872      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:47:39.872      293-320/? E/Genymotion﹕ Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
 04-16 13:4
```

Comment: Are u saving the images with the same name : **myimage.png** !

Comment: Stacktrace? Which line fails? Sorry, no Nostradamus here...

Comment: no now change the name

Comment: OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath,String.valueOf(i)+".png"));

Answer (score 0):

What you get from `l.getString("merchant_image")` is a network address. But you tried to access the file you didn't download from internet. If you try to download this file into local storage system, take a look at this:

```
try {
    File f = new File("yourfilename.mp3");
    if (f.exists()) {
        publishProgress(100,100);
    } else {
        int count;
        URL url = new URL("http://site:port/your/mp3file/here.mp3");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        long total = 0;
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int)(total/1024),lengthOfFile/1024);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Download Error: ", e.toString());
}
```

I hope you will be inspired from my codes.

Comment: l.getString("merchant_image") i am using json

Comment: like json {  merchant_image: "http://192.168.1.3:8080/emenu/images/restaurant1.png" passing several image url @SilentKnight

Comment: @Jack `String url = l.getString("merchant_image")`, the `url` is a file address stored in the server, right?

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look. And now, It can download the picture of the `url` into local storage system.

Comment: What does `ya k` mean? yes?